# View PDF in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

We are calling asp.net webapi to display PDF in html object, PDF is viewed perfectly in Chrome & Firefox. In Internet Exporer 11 pdf is not viewed instead [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivKAI.png) in thrown

Below is our source
HTML

```
    <object data="{{piData}}" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></object>
```

AngularJs

```
$scope.piData = null;
    $http.get('www.mydomain/pi', {
        params: {
            "piId": pPiId
        },
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    }).then(function (response) {

        var data = response.data;
        var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        $scope.piData = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
    }, function (err) {
        alert(err.data);
    });
```

How to resolve this error

Comment: From the error message, it looks like IE is using Adobe flash or shockwave flash object add on to load the PDF file and it is not identifying the .tmp file. If it is possible for you than you can try to modify your code to load the file as PDF or try to use HTML5 standards to load the PDF for IE because in future, Microsoft will remove the support for adobe add on from IE and Edge. Ref: https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2017/07/25/flash-on-windows-timeline/#1OJyliumeafqJISs.97

Answer (score 0):

```
    $scope.piData = null;
    $http.get('www.mydomain/pi', {
        params: {
            "piId": pPiId
        },
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    }).then(function(response) {
     if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        var data = response.data;
        var binary = atob(data);
        var len = binary.length;
        var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
        var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var blob1 = new Blob([view], {
            type: 'application/pdf'
        });
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob1, data);
}else {
 var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    $scope.piData = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
}
    }, function(err) {
        alert(err.data);
    });
```